# Как открыть вторую копию программы?

Tags: c++

Как сделать по нажатии кнопки, чтобы эта же программа открывалась, не закрывая исходной.

Comment: Ну и по дурацки же сформулирован вопрос !

Попробую догадаться, 

*Как программа может запустить еще один экземпляр  себя самой ?*

**Так ?**

-

@RconPro, ОС хотя бы укажите.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
......

string path (argv[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
   path += "  ";
   path += argv[i];
}

_popen (path.c_str(), "w");
```

Comment: А какую кнопку нажимать? Reset?

Comment: Quod scripsi sapienti sat

Comment: @mikillskegg Доктор, а поразборчивей можно писать?

Comment: Одну, две, *малое число* через popen() запустить (и забыть о них) конечно можно. А вот *много* не будет работать (pclose() вовремя надо вызывать).

Почему я про ОС спросил ? Потому что SIGCHLD в винде нет, не знаю как в ней асинхронно определить завершение процесса.

В \*nix с popen() тоже мороки много будет. Тут я бы для простоты из под fork() вызвал system(). (Халтурно запустил бы в фоне). 
Вообще такая халтура ненадежна (общий управляющий терминал, да и вообще надо понимать, что запускаемая программа делает с stdin (если это терминал, то делить они его не смогут))

**Т.е. вопрос не прост.*

Comment: system() из под fork()? Хоть бы exec()... shell-то зачем тревожить?
Да и вообще "эта же программа" -- fork(), точная копия.

Answer (score 1):

`system()` - это для халтурной простоты.

По-хорошему, 2 `fork()` (на pid первого `waitpid()`, а из второго `execl()`, но перед этим `setsid()` и надо понять по смыслу задачи, куда переключить stdin, stdout и stderr перед execl)

Это если надо запустить и забыть. И чтобы зомби не плодились.

Да, в запускающей программе неплохо бы убедиться в наличии close-on-exec  для файлов, не нужных запускаемой копии а также не забыть о семафорах и разделяемой памяти.

--

Как такое надо делать в винде, не знаю.